# QBasicTimer::start: QBasicTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qgis, pyqgis

I was trying to create a multi-window application for QGIS, but every time I exit I get a QBasicTimer error. It seems that I close all windows when I exit, but the error always shows up, and each time the number of error lines is different, depending on which window I exit from.

Here is my code.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import *

import mainSubSysWin_design

import mapAndCharWin
import mapAndCharWin_design

import compTechWin
import compTechWin_design

import locNetWin
import locNetWin_design


class mainSubSysWin (QtWidgets.QDialog, mainSubSysWin_design.Ui_Dialog) :
    
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.compTechButt.clicked.connect(self.compTechWin)
        self.compTech_window = compTechWin.compTechWin()
        self.compTech_window.backToMainButt.clicked.connect(self.toMainWin)
        
        self.charLocalButt.clicked.connect(self.netWin)
        self.locNet_window = locNetWin.locNetWin()
        self.locNet_window.toMainButt.clicked.connect(self.toMainWin)

        
        self.mapButt.clicked.connect(self.mapChar)
        self.mapChar_window = mapAndCharWin.mapAndCharWin()
        self.mapChar_window.backMapButt.clicked.connect(self.toMainWin)
        


    def compTechWin(self):
        self.compTech_window.show()
        self.hide()

    def netWin(self):
        self.locNet_window.show()
        self.hide()

    def mapChar(self):
        self.mapChar_window.show()
        self.hide()

    def toMainWin(self):
        self.show()
        self.compTech_window.hide()
        self.mapChar_window.hide()
        self.locNet_window.hide()

    def closeWin(self):
        self.compTech_window.close()
        self.mapChar_window.close()
        self.locNet_window.close()
        self.close()
        
def main():
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("qgis-ltr-dev", True)
    qgs=QgsApplication([],True)
    QgsCredentials.instance()
    qgs.initQgis()    
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    QgsProject.instance().read(dir_path+'/NEWproject/qgis222.qgz')
    print("yep")
    main_app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    #main_app.aboutToQuit.connect(exitHandler())
    window = mainSubSysWin()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(main_app.exec_())
    exit_code = qgs.exec_()
    qgs.exitQgis()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also is there any difference between closing a window with a button in form or clicking on a cross?

And this is the edited code

```
def main():
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("qgis-ltr-dev", True)
    qgs=QgsApplication([],True)
    QgsCredentials.instance()
    qgs.initQgis()    
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    QgsProject.instance().read(dir_path+'/NEWproject/qgis222.qgz')
    print("yep")
    window = mainSubSysWin()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(qgs.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: QgsApplication **is** a QApplication, you must not create (nor run) another Qt Application if one already exists.

Comment: @musicamante I commented out the lines about 'main_app' but the error remains

Comment: Are you really sure you need to call `exitQgis`? Since you're going to quit the program, python should theoretically take care of releasing all resources (but I don't know QGis that well). You should probably just use `sys.exit(qgs.exec_())`.

Comment: @musicamante I did as you wrote, but nothing has changed (_: you can see my edited code in the question block

Comment: Maybe you could ask on [gis.se], but please check their tour and faqs before asking there, I'm not completely sure you can ask such questions there.